# Recursive word group array searching

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array

I've been working on search function that will let me group specific words then recursively search for them in an array and I've coded myself into a hole I think.  This is my first foray into recursion and I'm sure I've bungled it up. I'm close but I can't seem to finish it correctly and was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

I'm working with bigrams.  I start with a list of bigrams pulled from current events.

"least, 6", "6, texas", "powerball,jackpot", "killed, texas", "texas, tornado", "suspect, parade" etc etc.  There are 50 unique phrases.

What I'm attempting to do is find related words and group them.  Using the above data the words that would group would be:  "least, 6, texas, killed, tornado" since they are all related.

My method was.  Take the first bigram, split it up, search all the bigrams and wherever those two words are found grab those bigrams, split them and repeat once more.  That should get me all the matches. ( or enough to do what I need to do ).

I'm to the point where I'm pretty sure I"m getting the correct data but i'm having issues removing those words from the array so they are not searched over and over.  Each iteration of teh search should get smaller since the number of words is less.

Ok code.  ( note the recursive function is not mine, that part actually works.)  Also yes, it's messy.  Like I said, just learning, and I was planning on cleaning it up afterwards.

The array_diff near the bottom was supposed to remove the already searched words and then repeat the proces.   Thanks in advance.

```
<?php

$mainbigramarray = array();
$explodedarray = array();
$resarr = array();
$i=1;

function recursive_array_search($needle,$haystack,$subloop = false) {
    if($subloop === false) $resarr = array();
    foreach($haystack as $key=>$value) {
        $current_key=$key;
        if(is_string($needle)) $needle = trim(strtolower($needle));
        if(is_string($value)) $value = trim(strtolower($value));
        if($needle===$value OR (is_array($value) && recursive_array_search($needle,$value,true) === true)) {
            $resarr[] = $current_key;
            if($subloop === true) return true;
        }
    }
    return $resarr;
}       


WHILE($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{          
    unset($bigrams);
    $bigram = $rows['bigram'];
    $count = $rows['m'];
    $rid = $rows['RID'];
    $bgexplode = explode(" ", $bigram);

    foreach($bgexplode as $bg) {
        $bigrams[] = $bg;

    }
    $workingbigram [] = $bigrams;
    array_push($bigrams, $count);
    $mainbigramarray[] = $bigrams;

    }   
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr>"; 
    $firstrun = array();
    $secondrun = array();
    $resultrun = array();
    $matchset1 = array();
    $bigramset = array();

    echo "<td>"; 


    foreach($workingbigram as $bgg) {  //steps through the main array that holds the exploded bigram                
        unset($firstrun);
        foreach($bgg as $word) { //steps through both words of the bigram

            $search1 = recursive_array_search($word, $mainbigramarray);
            $firstrun[$word] = $search1;
        }
        $bigramset[] = $firstrun;
    } 



    //echo "<pre>";
    //print_r($bigramset);
    //echo "</pre>";
    echo "</td>";


    echo "<td>";
    $counter = 0;
    foreach($bigramset as $key1=>$value1) { //get the array that holds the exploded biram
        foreach($value1 as $key2=>$value2) { //get the array that holds the ids of whre the word is found
            //echo "$key2<br>";
            foreach($value2 as $searchid) { //gets the id to pull the matching exploded bigrams from. 
                unset($bigresult);
                foreach($workingbigram[$searchid] as $wordresult) { //gets word to seasrch from by iding mainbigram array
                    $bigresult = recursive_array_search($wordresult, $mainbigramarray);
                }

                $resultrun[] = $bigresult;
            }

        }           
        foreach($resultrun as $key3=>$value3) {
            foreach($value3 as $finalsearchid) {
                foreach($workingbigram[$finalsearchid] as $lastsearchterm) {
                    $finalwordset[] = $lastsearchterm;
                }
            }

        }
        $finalwordset = array_unique($finalwordset);
        foreach($finalwordset as $word) {
            $total = recursive_array_search($word, $mainbigramarray);
            $totalsum = 0;
            foreach($total as $lastlookup) {

                unset($bucket);
                foreach($mainbigramarray[$lastlookup] as $total6) {
                    echo "$total6<br>"; 
                    $bucket[] = $total6;
                }
                //echo "Score:" . $bucket[2] . "<br>";     
                $totalsum = $bucket[2] + $totalsum;
                //echo "TOTAL SUM: $totalsum<br>";
            }   
            echo "TOTAL SUM: $totalsum<br>";
        }           
        $bigramset = array_diff($bigramset[$i], $finalwordset);
        //if ($counter ==1) break;
        $i++;   
    }           
    //echo"<pre>";
    //print_r($newarray);
    //echo "</pre>";
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";
```

Comment: *" I was planning on cleaning it up afterwards."* Those cleanings never happen then, we see it every day :) Instead clean your code the minute you spot the dust. In the end, it's very much likely you don't run into such programming problems then you've asked about.

Answer (score 0):

This returns an array with keys as a word and values as an array of associated words.

```
$bigrams = array("least, 6", "6, texas", "powerball,jackpot", "killed, texas", "texas, tornado", "suspect, parade" );
$results = array();

function searchBigrams($val,$i,$bigrams){
    global $results;
    if(!isset($results[$val]) || !is_array($results[$val])){ $results[$val] = array(); }
    foreach($bigrams as $b){
        $nodes = explode(',',$b);
        $nodes = array_map('trim',$nodes);
        $r = array_search($val,$nodes);
        if(($r = array_search($val,$nodes)) !== false){ 
            $new_bigrams = $bigrams;
            if(($key = array_search($b, $new_bigrams)) !== false) {
                unset($new_bigrams[$key]);
            }
            if($r == 0){
                if(!in_array($nodes[1],$results[$i])){ $results[$i][] = $nodes[1]; }
                if(!in_array($nodes[1],$results[$i])){ $results[$val][] = $nodes[1]; }
                if(!isset($results[$nodes[1]])){
                    $results[$nodes[1]] = array();
                }
                if(!in_array($val,$results[$nodes[1]])){
                    $results[$nodes[1]][] = $val;
                }
                searchBigrams($nodes[1],$i,$new_bigrams);                   
            } else {
                if(!in_array($nodes[0],$results[$i])){ $results[$i][] = $nodes[0]; }
                if(!in_array($nodes[0],$results[$i])){ $results[$val][] = $nodes[0]; }
                if(!isset($results[$nodes[0]])){
                    $results[$nodes[0]] = array();
                }
                if(!in_array($val,$results[$nodes[0]])){
                    $results[$nodes[0]][] = $val;
                }
                searchBigrams($nodes[0],$i,$new_bigrams);
            }
        }
    }
}

foreach($bigrams as $b){
    $nodes = explode(',',$b);
    $nodes = array_map('trim',$nodes);
    foreach($nodes as $n){
        searchBigrams($n,$n,$bigrams);
    }
}

var_dump($results);
```